# Drawing Images from a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, image, graphics, concurrency

I am making a program where a character will be animated in a thread away from the rest of the program.

```
Thread trollAnimation = new Thread() {

    public void run() {
        if (battling) {
            frame++;

            switch (frame) {
            case 1: case 5: case 9:
                g.drawImage(troll1, 0, 0, null);
                break;
            case 2: case 4: case 6: case 8:
                g.drawImage(troll2, 0, 0, null);
                break;
            case 3: case 7:
                g.drawImage(troll3, 0, 0, null);
                break;
            case 10:
                g.drawImange(troll4, 0, 0, null);
                break;
            }

            if (frame == 10) {
                frame = 1;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

On each line that says g.drawImage..., an error is thrown that says "g cannot be resolved".  In addition to the problem with drawing images, how do i stop the thread properly when battling == false?

Comment: you cant draw outside of the main AWT thread in Java...sorry

Comment: can i write something like paint.drawImage(...); so that the thread will send the image to my paint method?

Comment: you cannot execute drawing on anything but the main thread.

Comment: ok. thank you. Just for future knowledge, what is the best way to end a thread?

Comment: You CAN draw outside the EDT, but you SHOULDN'T, EVER ... EVER ...You need away that you can tell the rendering engine that it needs to update the graphics of the character and have it drawn within the context of the EDT

Comment: @arrowheadx16 The best way to end a thread is to let it exit the `run` method.

Comment: It seems from the logic that this would be better served by a single animated GIF.

Comment: the run method will complete and the thread terminates.  That is the best way, otherwise you have to look at interrupting the thread of which there are many questions on SO already and Im not going to repeat that here.

Comment: *"..what is the best way to end a thread?"*  That particular thread?  Set `battling=false;`.

Comment: thank you. I'll try a animated GIF later.